# Backbone.Marionette has no method 'bindTo'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Trying Marionette for the first time.
Following the example here:

https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#binding-to-itemview-events

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bindTo'
```

I have also tried copy/pasting the entire code snippet from the example, this also throws that error. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in v0.9.6, 2 days ago. Grab the latest version and it should work fine now.